# Как сделать поиск по Xpath в Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

Хочу достать цены на странице. Мой `xpath` выглядит таким образом

```
//div[contains(@class,"product-card-price__current-wrap")]
```

Но при поиске элемента выходит ошибка, что элемент не найден

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath))
```

В `driver.PageSource` я наблюдаю что страница полностью загрузилась, но все равно не находит этот `div`

p.s
https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/ffbf6a1853c91b80/62-smartfon-samsung-galaxy-s21-128-gb-seryj/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А так? `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-card-price__current-wrap"))`

Comment: А по поводу XPath, попробовать можно так `//div[contains(@class,'product-card-price__current-wrap')]`